# 500 error when downloading a file from the Google Drive API

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to download some files using the Google Drive API. My code looks like this: https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/devguide/files#reading_files. I am also making regular HTTP requests to the /v3/files/...?alt=media endpoint elsewhere. They were all working fine, but now whenever I make these requests, I get 500 errors.

In the documentation, Google recommends doing exponential backoff when you see 500s, but it's been broken for over an hour now. Has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: What are your logs ?

Comment: The response from Google is 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: slow down your code and try the last request again.   You are being throttled.  Google recommends we  implement exponential backoff in our code

Comment: if he was being throttled, the http status would be 403, not 500. If you do end up being throttled, do NOT do exponential backoff.

Comment: Woke up this morning and these requests are working again. I want to use this in production and am somewhat concerned about it breaking for hours with no status update (at least that I could find).